# Is CPCV similar to bootstrap?

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap

I am writing to ask if the Combinatorial (Purged) Cross-Validation" method of Marcos Lopez de Prado's "Advances in Financial Machine Learning" book is similar to the idea of bootstrap. If not, what is the key difference? It seems like bootstrap is based on permutation (resampling with replacement) and C(P)CV is based on combinations (resampling without replacement)? At the same time, I suppose the key goal between both methods is to generate as many artificial samples from the same dataset?

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences is that bootstrap does not preserve the order of the observations. It will sample observations (or blocks of observations, if using Block Bootstrap) in random order. Because you mentioned MLdP, I assume that you are working with financial time series. A possible disadvantage of bootstrapping is that it will not always preserve some properties of the time series such as autocorrelation and volatility clustering. The Tapered Block Bootstrap mitigates but does not completely eliminate those limitations.

In contrast, CPCV preserves the original order of the samples and just uses different parts of the dataset as training and validation data.